# Getting invalid syntax error when i try to start yugabytes DB

Tags: yugabytedb

I have installed yugabytes DB in linux machine and when i try to start the cluster using yugabyted and getting error as invalid syntax. Please help how to resolve this issue.

./bin/yugabyted status
File "./bin/yugabyted", line 1430
with open(out_log, "a") as out_log, open(err_log, "a") as err_log:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Python version using - 2.6.6
Linux Version - 2.6.32-754.31.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: Python 2.6 is something like 12 years old now.  You're going to have a hard time finding *anything* that will actually work with it.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I will upgrade to higher version and try it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Python 2.6 issue where multiple contextmanagers in the same line are not supported - https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement. While the fix for this particular error should be simple, Python 2.6 is quite outdated at this point - retired in 2013 according to https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-269/ - and I would recommend upgrading to Python 2.7.

Comment: Thanks I will upgrade and let you know.